# Trying to run executable - file or directory does not exist, but file exists. And I can execute it, but only from within the directory it's in

Tags: linux

As the title suggest, I'm trying to run an executable.  When I attempt to run it from other directories, I get the "file or directory does not exist" error.  However when I'm in the directory the file is in, I have no problem.  Any suggestions?

Everyone else who has this problem is never able to execute their file, regardless of what directory they are currently in!

Thank you!

Comment: Please explain. Where is the program, and what command are you using to execute it.

Comment: Directory containing executable not in path?

Comment: Sounds like you have current directory (`.`) in your `$PATH`, but you don't have whatever directory the file is in in your `$PATH`.

Comment: for example, I am trying to run the file "virus.tmp", located in /tmp/virus.tmp (this is for a software securities class, no need to worry!).  When I use the command ./tmp/virus.tmp from another directory, say /usr/whatever, I get the error no file or directory exists.  However when I go to /tmp, and run ./virus.tmp, it works without any issues

Comment: actually also just found out that if I attempt to run the program from the root directory, it works fine! It's just not working when I try and run it from the /usr directories!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute /tmp/virus.tmp, you need to run:

```
/tmp/virus.tmp
```

Your attempt to instead run:

```
./tmp/virus.tmp
```

fails because what it tries to do is find the program inside the `tmp` directory of the current directory. (`.` is the current directory.) For example, if you are in `/home/user/` and type `./tmp/prog`, it will try to execute `/home/user/tmp/prog`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Follow up question.  In my script, I'm changing virus.tmp to ls(cp /bin/ls /tmp/virus.tmp).  Now, when I call virus.tmp using /tmp/virus.tmp, I get the same original error

Comment: @user1887163 Always confirm that the file is actually executable (with `ls -l` you can see whether its executable bit is set.)